# keep same session alive while long running database query returns result

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I want to keep same session alive while long running database query returns result, I want to show this data in chart on front end. I am using asp.net and want to show data using jquery ajax.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I have query database which has complex queries so it will take much time and after getting data I want to show that data in chart.

Answer (score 2):

Please increase your session.Timeout as given below :

```
Session.Timeout = 60;    // Here 60 is in minutes i.e 1 hour. Modify as needed.
```